# Segmentation fault while pointer assignment

Tags: c++, c

Write a program to reverse the direction of a given singly-linked list. In other words, after the reversal all pointers should now point backwards.

I am trying to solve above problem. I wrote functions for insertion,search and deletion and printing for the singly linked list.

my print function is as follows

```
void print(list **l)
{
    list *p=*l;
    for(int i=0;p;i++)
    {
        cout<<p->item<<endl;
        p=p->next;
    }
}
```

it works fine printing all values in the list.

but in the main function if I do the same assignment like this

```
list *p=*l;
```

it gives me segmentation fault. my main function is as follow

```
main()
{
    list **l;
    *l=NULL;
    int n;
    while(cin>>n)
    insert(l,n);
    list *p=*l;
    list *prev=NULL;
    list *next;
    while(p)
    {
        next=p->next;
        p->next=prev;
        prev=p;
        if(next==NULL)
        *l=p;
        p=next;
    }       
    print(l);
}
```

my insert function is as follows

```
void insert(list **l,int x)
{
    list *p;
    p=(list *)malloc(sizeof(list));
    p->item=x;
    p->next=*l;
    *l=p;
}
```

what is the difference between the assignment I do in print function and the main function? why I don't get any error in print function and I get a segmentation fault in the main function?

if my function is like this

```
main()
{
    list **l;
    *l=NULL;
    int n;
    while(cin>>n)
    insert(l,n);
    print(l);
}
```

I am not getting any error I am able to insert and print values of the list.

Comment: `list ** l;`is a dangling pointer, so `*l=NULL;` is undefined behavior.

Comment: @enobayram I am inserting values right?

Comment: Yes, you're performing an insertion in the `insert` function correctly, but your overall approach is inappropriate even for C, let alone C++. Is there any reason why you're not using `std::list<int>`? Even if you want to code like C, use `list *l = NULL;` and pass it around as `print(&l)`.

Comment: I know how to use list<int>, I am trying to solve the problem mentioned if I use list<int> I can't solve that right?

Comment: Avoid malloc/free in C++, they can cause trouble since they aren't compatible with new/delete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write

```
list **l;
*l=NULL;
```

You're dereferencing an invalid pointer, so run into undefined behavior.

Inside the function, you're probably passing a valid pointer as argument. For example

```
list* l;
void print(&l)
```

In this case, `&l` is of type `list**` - and it points to a dangling `list*`, so dereferencing it will yield a pointer (`l` itself). `l` isn't initialized, but not reading from it is ok.

Comment: I updated my post, in the second case I am not getting any error.

Comment: @user2086900 it's undefined behavior either way. The lines I pointed out are invalid.

Comment: @user2086900 DO NOT rely on trial and error in C/C++. You'll be in very big trouble very soon. Most other languages guard you against certain types of errors, so most bugs are easily found, but in C/C++ messing with pointers can cause REALLY REALLY hard to find bugs.

Answer (score 1):

You write:

```
list **l;
*l=NULL;
```

But l isn't assigned, you don't know it's value, so *l=NULL is undefined behaviour, since you don't know which area of memory you're changing.